# Get all rows in Json format with API-Rest Cassandra

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

I have the following code that allows me to retrieve the first keyspace:

```
def Query(str):

   auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='admin', password='root')
   cluster = Cluster(['hostname'], auth_provider=auth_provider)
   session = cluster.connect('system')
   rows = session.execute(str)
   keyspaces = []
   row_list = list(rows)
   for x in range(len(row_list)):
       return row_list[0] 

@app.route('/keyspaces')
def all(): 
   return Query('select json * from schema_keyspaces')
```

[image]
[image] 
I would like not only get all the keyspaces, but also their attributes and that in JSON document, how I can proceed ?

Thanks,

Comment: Umm. You return in a loop. Of course you get only the first one

Comment: Yes that is the problem, I want to return all the rows in a JSON document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a loop that only runs once, you need to collect all the elements

```
rows = session.execute(str)
return jsonify(list(rows))
```

Note that you should ideally not be creating a new cassandra connection for each query you need to make, but that's unrelated to the current problem